# Ruby, spreadsheet by key

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using ruby to call spreadsheet_by_key from a google document. The first page that I call works great, however when i try to duplicate it and use the second tab on the page it does not work. Let me better explain with some examples.

I am using:

data = session.spreadsheet_by_key("spreadsheetkeygoeshere").worksheets[0]

```
# Get Graph-Data
(2..data.num_rows).each do |column|
    key = data[column, 10]
    title = data[column, 2]
    current = data[column, 3]
    goal = data[column, 4]

    send_event(key, title: title, min: 0, max: goal, value: current)
```

end

This works great and returns all of the expected values. Here is the problem I am having.. this is on the page 1 the first page that loads when you open google docs. Now lets say I wan't to make a new spreadsheet on the same doc just under a new tab with a different name and display that data as well

Here is how i change the code:
data1 = session.spreadsheet_by_key("spreadsheetkeygoeshere").worksheets[1]

```
# Get Graph-Data
(2..data1.num_rows).each do |column|
    key = data[column, 10]
    puts key
    title = data[column, 1]
    current = data[column, 5]
    goal = data[column, 6]

    send_event(key, title: title, min: 0, max: goal, value: current)
end
```

SO i changed the .worksheets[0] to .worksheets[1]
also i changed
(2..data.num_rows) to (2..data1.num_rows)

Also i changed the data = to data1 =

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong that causes the second spreadsheet to not get pulled ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "the second spreadsheet to not get pulled" what exactly does happen instead? What error messages do you get, if any? What values do the objects data and data1 have. In the code you posted, you wrote key = data[column, 10] : please try again changing all the data to data1 and post what happens.

Comment: What worked was i went in and changed data1 to just data and everything works. Seeing as the code is only reading what data= and not what data1 =, etc. Thanks for the help Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked was Cameron suggestion. I went in and changed everything to just `data =` instead of `data1=` and that fixed the problem.